# Is `-P` the same as `-ap` for builtin `type`?

Tags: bash

From Bash manual

> ```
> type [-afptP] [name ...]
> ```
>
> For each name, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a
>   command name.
>
> If the -p option is used, type either returns the name of the disk fi
>   le that would be executed, or nothing if -t would not return ‘file’.
>
> **The -P option forces a path search for each name, even if -t would not return ‘file’.**
>
> If a command is hashed, -p and -P print the hashed value, which is not
>   necessarily the file that appears first in $PATH.
>
> If the -a option is used, `type` returns all of the places that contain
>   an executable named **`file`** . This includes aliases and functions, if
>   and only if the -p option is not also used.

1. Does `file` in "If the -a option is used, `type` returns all of the
   places that contain an executable named **file**" mean `name`
   instead?
2. Is `-P` the same as `-ap`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Most likely, yes.
2. Not quite. Just so the use case for `-P` is clear: `-P` can be used as a "stronger" `-p`. For example:

   `$ type [
   [ is a shell builtin`

   `$ type -p [`

   In the above, `type -p [` returns nothing, because `type -t [` says `builtin` (this makes sense, the manual says that `-p` behaves this way, after all).

   However:

   `$type -P [
   /usr/bin/[`

   The flag `-P` forces the search to be within the `PATH` variable, so we get some output.

---

That said, `type -ap` and `type -P` differ, on my system, in the amount of duplicates they output. `type -ap echo`, for example, produces `/usr/bin/echo` three times, while `type -P echo` gives me only one line. This is most likely because /usr/bin is symlinked to a few different places.
There's one more (subtle) difference:

> If the -a option is used, type returns all of the places that contain an **executable** named `file`. This includes aliases and functions, if and only if the `-p` option is not also used.

So, if I do `sudo touch /bin/bogus`, `type -P bogus` happily returns `/usr/bin/bogus`, while `type -ap bogus` gives me nothing.